# Recursive pairwise braces matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Let's consider this piece of code which does not belong to any known language:

```
foo() {
    bar() {
       bar();
    }

    baz() {
        // Content baz
        qux() {
           // Content qux
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to iteratively process each `function` by calling a subroutine which receives: the function name, the arguments, the indentation level and the content.

So far I have written this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
$_ = do {local $/; <>};       
s/([{}])/$1.($1 eq '{'?++$i:$i--).$1/eg;     
parse($_);

sub parse {
    local $_ = shift;
    while (/(?<name>\w+)\s*\((?<args>.*?)\)\s*\{(\d)\{(?<content>.*?)\}(?<level>\3)\}/gs) {
        parse($+{content});
        process($+{content}, $+{args}, $+{level}, $+{content});
    }
}

sub process {
    my ($name, $args, $level, $content) = @_;
    #...
}
```

The tricky idea is to replace in-place each matched brace `{` with an indentation number. So this:

```
{
    {
    }
}
```

will become this:

```
{1{
    {2{
    }2}
}1}
```

It allows to easily write the parsing regex which simply become:

```
qr/
  \w+          # name
  \s* \(.*?\)  # arguments
  \s* \{(\d)\{ # opening brace
  .*?          # content
  \s* \}\1\}   # closing brace
/x
```

> How can I rewrite this without this trick?

Note that the choice of `{1{` could be anything else like `{(1)`, `{1-`, `{[1]` or even `{1✈`

Comment: Can there be quoted braces inside the function, for example inside strings? Or inside comments?

Comment: No there is neither strings or quoted values in this primitive language. Good question btw.

Comment: I am not sure if this could be of interest, but see also : [An Overview of Lexing and Parsing](http://www.perl.com/pub/2012/10/an-overview-of-lexing-and-parsing.html)

Comment: Recursion already does the trick for you. What are you trying to do, rewrite it  with correct formatted indentation? You can do that without the trick.

Comment: Would [recursive regular expressions](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text) help? Example: `/(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})/`

Comment: @HåkonHægland It's exactly what I was looking for. I should more practive with recursive regex. One question that I may ask is about the efficiency of the recursive regexes in comparaison with my original implementation. I should check that on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using recursive regular expressions. For example:

```
/(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*\})/
```

will match a group of balanced braces. For more information, see

- [Can I use Perl regular expressions to match balanced text?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text) in [perlfaq6](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq6.html),
- Perl documentation [`"Extended patterns"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), and
- [`extract_bracketed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#extract_bracketed) in [`Text::Balanced`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced).

Comment: The use of `Marpa:R2` could be a nice alternative. I am afraid the complexity of this parser and its understanding can become higher than a low-level regex implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You will have a hard time doing this with a recursive regex because you can only get the last value of each capturing group and will lose all of the intervening values. This task is more suited to a parser like [`Parse::RecDescent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Parse::RecDescent;

sub process {
    my ($name, $args, $depth) = @_;
    say "$depth - $name($args)";
}

my $grammar = q{
    { my $indent = 0; }
    startrule     : expression(s /;/)
    expression    : function_call
                  | function_def[$indent]
    function_call : identifier '(' arglist ')' ';'
    function_def  : identifier '(' arglist ')' '{' expression[ $arg[0]++ ](s?) '}'
                  { main::process( $item{identifier}, join(',', @$item{arglist}), $arg[0] ) }
    arglist       : identifier(s? /,/)
    identifier    : /\w+/
};

# Tell parser to ignore spaces and C99 one-line comments
my $skip_spaces_and_comments = qr{ (?: \s+ | // .*?$ )* }mxs;
$Parse::RecDescent::skip = $skip_spaces_and_comments;

my $parser = Parse::RecDescent->new($grammar) or die 'Bad grammar';

my $text = do { local $/; <DATA> };

defined $parser->startrule($text) or die 'Failed to parse';

__DATA__
foo() {
    bar() {
       bar();
    }

    baz() {
        // Content baz
        qux() {
           // Content qux
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
2 - bar()
1 - qux()
2 - baz()
3 - foo()
```

Note that the depths are inverted (1 is the most nested) and this doesn't return the contents of the function definitions, but it should get you started.

Comment: The meaning of this sentence is not very clear to me: `You will have a hard time doing this with a recursive regex because you can only get the last value of each capturing group and will lose all of the intervening values`

Comment: The issue I run into with `BNF` like parsers is that all the grammar must be defined. In my example, if I add the word `bug` after `// Content qux`, the parser fails with a very obscure message for the final user. I feel that using a low-level regex approach would be a more robust approach since the whole grammar does not need to be defined. Am I wrong?

Comment: First comment: `perl -E'$_="{foo{bar}}";say $2 if /(\{((?:(?>[^{}]+)|(?0))*)\})/'` uses a recursive regex to match nested curly braces. `$2` captures the contents of the curlies, but only stores the last value (i.e. the outermost). So you can capture `foo{bar}` but not `bar`.

Comment: Second comment: All you have to do is change the grammar to accept random identifiers inside function definitions. (That's essentially what you're doing with `.*` in a regex.) Also, I haven't done any error handling in my example; see the section on [error handling](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent#Error-handling) in the Parse::RecDescent docs for ways to make errors much more user friendly.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBackNot Could you please give me an example in order to accept other statements than the ones I am looking for?